Go MYSQL Connection pool behavior
I have an app which uses MySQL connection pooling. I am using the standard  database/sql package. During app startup, I create the connection pool and set the following options on the pool
    pool, err = sql.Open("driver-name", *dsn)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer pool.Close()

    pool.SetMaxOpenConns(256)
    pool.SetMaxIdleConns(256)
    pool.SetConnMaxLifetime(3*time.Hour)
    pool.SetConnMaxIdleTime(3*time.Hour)

Then I use this pool to make queries and return the connection back to the pool. The high level flow of making queries is
// Create conn

conn, err := pool.Conn(ctx)
if err != nil {
   return err
}
defer conn.Close()

// do operation
result, err := conn.ExecContext(ctx, query, args)
if err != nil {
   return
}
...
...

My expectation is that the defer conn.Close() will put the connection back in the pool without closing them. I have an async go-routing which periodically calls Stats() to print the information about open/in-use/idle connections and I am noticing a sawtooth pattern for open/idle connections. They both go up as request volume increases and then trend down to very small values within few minutes. Shouldn't the connections stay idle for much longer time because that is the value I am setting for MaxIdleTime and MaxLifetime ?

